# HTTPCLIENT: Authentication for https protocol on an asp page 

Tags: httpclient

I need to access an asp page running on 'https' protocol.
I am facing problems at authentication part itself. The response object returns "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" but i am getting redirected to Login page itself.

Following is my code:

```
public FileDownloadHttpWrapper(String url,String username, String password)
{
    SchemeRegistry supportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();
    supportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("https", 
    SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

    // prepare parameters
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,supportedSchemes);
    mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm,params);            
    mClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(null,AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
        );
}

private Object getRequest(String url)
{
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("/EvalMuniMKT/mainmenu.asp");
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(url, 443, "https");

    try
    {
        // execute the GET
        HttpResponse resp = mClient.execute(target,get);

        HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();

        System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine());            
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));   
    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        // release any connection resources used by the method    
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the asp site uses form based login (session), not **http basic authentication**. For that you may need to do login form post and hold cookie in context and pass the context while executing the actual request.

something like :

```
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    // Create local HTTP context
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
          hc.execute(httpget, localContext);
```